# Trying to prevent duplicate username creation in Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Hi I am trying to prevent duplicate user name creation, and my application keeps trying to redirect me to a hypothetical account page and keeps throwing username undefined error in my erb file, and I am actually trying to redirect back to signup page if the user name already exist.

Here is my model for User class:

```
class User <ActiveRecord::Base
    include Slugifiable::InstanceMethods
    extend Slugifiable::ClassMethods
    
    validates_uniqueness_of :username, case_sensitive: false <---This should validate if username exist
    has_many :players

    has_secure_password
    
    
  


end
```

Here is my  user controller post method where it should either create or redirect back to signup page and give a flash message that the user name exist already

```
post '/signup' do
        if params[:username] == "" || params[:email] == "" || params[:password] == "" || params[:name] == ""
            flash[:notice] = "<h3 class ='alert'>Please fill-in info!</h3>"
            redirect to '/signup'
        
        
        else
            if @user
              flash[:notice] = "<h3>Username already exist, try anoter one.</h3>"
              redirect to '/signup'
            else
              @user = User.create(:username => params[:username], :email => params[:email], :password => 
 params[:password], :name => params[:name])
              session[:user_id] = @user.id
              redirect to '/account'
            
            end
        end
    end
```

When I try to create a duplicate username for testing purposes....it keeps redirecting me to an account page but throws an error that username is undefined from erb file. It works fine when creating a completely new username though. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

"throws an error ... from erb" sounds like there's an issue in an ERB file somewhere?

`User.create` probably silently fails when the uniqueness check triggers, i.e. it sounds like it sets `@user.username` to `nil`, or `@user` itself is `nil`.

You also never defined what it should do when the validation check fails.

You can:

- use `User.create!` to raise an exception.
- check `@user.valid?` and `@user.errors` for any errors, and report them to the user

Comment: I will have to clone it and try this method as well.